# Why does my login page keep reloading, without trying to authenticate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication

In Controllers/AccountController.cs:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Account/Login
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
    ...
}
```

In web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/Home/Index" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

In Views/Account/Login.aspx:

```
<script runat="server" type="text/C#">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {...}
    protected void OnAuthenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e) {...}
    protected void OnLoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e){...}
    protected void OnLoginError(object sender, EventArgs e){...}
</script>

...

<asp:Login ID="login1" runat="server" 
           DestinationPageUrl="~/Views/Home/Index.aspx"
           OnAuthenticate="OnAuthenticate" 
           OnLoggedIn="OnLoggedIn" 
           OnLoginError="OnLoginError">
    ...
    <asp:Button ID="loginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login1" Text="Login" ValidationGroup="login1" TabIndex="4" />
    ...
</asp:Login>
```

`Page_Load` is called, but then `OnAuthenticate`, `OnLoggedIn`, and `OnLoginError` are never called. Why is that?

I am using MVC, and what happens after clicking the "Login" button is I am taken back to the AccountController. This returns the Login.aspx View, so the login page just gets reloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up re-writing everything from scratch, using Razor instead of ASPX.
I don't know how I could have fixed the issue in this question, and I took a completely different approach.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing Web Forms with MVC - you can't do that.

Comment: Oh dear. So what am I supposed to do? I'm using Ext.Net.

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged that code as `text/javascript` instead of `text/c#` with a `runat=server` tag.

Comment: You're right, that was wrong, thank you! However this did not solve my problem. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong script type should be type="text/C#"

**Change**

```
<script runat="server" type="text/javascript">
```

**To**

```
<script runat="server" type="text/C#">
```

Comment: You're right, that was wrong, thank you! However this did not solve my problem. I have edited my question.

Comment: You are welcome. Can you show me your page tag you might have code behind file?

Comment: `<%@ Page Title="Login" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>`

Comment: Can you remove Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" ?

Comment: Nothing changed upon doing that. Thanks though.

Comment: What happens is after clicking the "Login" button I am taken directly back to the AccountController, which returns the Login.aspx View where I just was. So the page just keeps reloading itself instead of moving on to authenticate.